# ZSH script exits even though ERR_EXIT is off

Tags: while-loop, signals, zsh, pipeline, sigint

I have this pipeline in my shell script. It's meant to prompt the user to select PulseAudio sources to record with ffmpeg, but to the best of my knowledge, that doesn't matter for this specific issue.

```
integer num_sources=0
pactl list short sources \
    | while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ "$line" =~ '^([[:digit:]]+)\s+(\S+)' ]]; then
        echo "#$match[1]: $match[2]"
      fi; done \
    | (fzf -m --prompt='Select audio source: ' || true) \
    | while IFS= read -r src_line; do if [[ "$src_line" =~ '^#([[:digit:]]+)' ]]; then
        local pulsesrc="$match[1]"
        (( num_sources++ ))
        ffpulseopts+=(
            -f pulse
            -i "$pulsesrc"
        )
      fi; done
```

My issue is that, if I remove the `|| true` from the fzf invocation, leaving fzf by means of pressing Escape, which causes a non-zero exit code, will cause the entire script to terminate. I don't understand why this happens, even though neither the `ERR_EXIT` nor the `ERR_RETURN` options are set. `PIPE_FAIL` is not set either, though I'm not sure how it would come into play here.

```
λ unsetopt | egrep '^(err|pipe)'
errexit
errreturn
pipefail
```

I have verified this issue with shorter examples as well; the following snippet will not print `foo` if you exit fzf with Escape. This doesn't happen when `fzf` is replaced with `false`, so I was able to trace the issue back to the exit code, which is 130 (indicating SIGINT) when pressing Escape.

```
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | fzf | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | false | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
foo
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
```

However, if you remove the loop, it will print as expected.

```
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | (exit 130); echo foo
foo
```

Even when you add other parts to the pipeline, it will still continue to print `foo` properly

```
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | (exit 130) | false; echo foo
foo
λ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | (exit 130) | true; echo foo
foo
```

After some fiddling, I found out that it's not just the loop either. It only happens when a middle part of the pipe exits with `SIGINT` **AND** the loop is the last part of the pipeline.

```
λ (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
foo
λ false | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
λ true | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo
λ false | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done | false; echo foo
foo
λ true | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done | false; echo foo
foo
λ false | (exit 130) | false; echo foo
foo
```

I'm stumped here, and don't really know where to go without a hack like `|| true` (`|| false` works as well as it turns the SIGINT exit code into a "regular" error exit code).

Edit: Upon request, here is the output of `setopt`.

```
λ setopt
alwaystoend
autocd
autopushd
completeinword
extendedglob
extendedhistory
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histignoredups
histignorespace
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
kshglob
longlistjobs
monitor
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
pushdminus
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

Edit 2: Some system context upon request

I am on an up-to-date (as of May 2nd, 2020, 19:04) Arch Linux, with ZSH 5.8.

Comment: I can not reproduce your case. With the last examples, I get _foo_ printed every time, including `false | (exit 130) | while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done; echo foo`.

Comment: Even though you claim that you have not set _errexit_ etc., I still would run a `setopt` to verify, which options are changed from their default. One never knows.....

Comment: @user1934428 I added the output of `setopt` to my question.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual with your options. For the safe side, maybe you could also report the zsh version you are using. Having said this, I finally managed in one installation to reproduce your issue: It's on MacOS Mojave, using zsh 5.3, where I get your behaviour. If this slipped in during a version update, you may want to report it as a bug to the zsh bugtracker (I don't think it relates to the OS).

Comment: @user1934428 Added my OS and the ZSH version I'm using.

Comment: Since nobody had so far a reasonable explanation for this effect, and you are really up-to-date, I would open a bug report. In Zsh, this is done via the mailing list _zsh-workers@zsh.org_. In case it is not a bug, but some obscure feature, maybe you can post the answer you got from the list here on SO.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming it would come to this when people were struggling to even repro my issue. Still, thank you for all your help. Will make sure to update.